# My query mixes up with arrays on execution

Tags: php, sql

Right, hello.

I've been working on a website template and I've coded a forum-like section, but simply discussion threads, and now, I'm having struggles with a specific query. This.

```
SELECT * FROM cms_discussions d JOIN cms_discussions_comments c ON d.id = c.discussionid ORDER BY c.time DESC LIMIT 10
```

I thought it would be easy enough to see how others have their question answered on how to order one table by another table's row. So I tried their method, but now it's mixing it up with each other. This is how it used to look like when I was sorting the threads by their IDs

```
SELECT * FROM cms_discussions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

And this is how it looked.
[image]

While using the SQL query I first provided, the outcome came out kinda wrong. The author of the thread was changed to 'server' (which was the author field from *cms_discussions_comments*), so basically, the 'author' field from *cms_discussion* gets replaced with the 'author' field from *cms_discussions_comments*. How I display the threads are quite simply.

```
<?php
    $response = $databaseHandle->query("SELECT * FROM cms_discussions d JOIN cms_discussions_comments c ON d.id = c.discussionid ORDER BY c.time DESC LIMIT 10");
    while($row = $response->fetch_assoc()) { 
        stripslashes_array($row);
    ?>
        <table class="row" onclick="window.location.href = '/discussion/<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>/';">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 50px"><img src="/styles/<?php echo $styleConfig["theme"]; ?>/album/discussions/<?php echo ($row["active"] == 1)?("status_info"):("status_locked"); ?>.png"></td>
                <td><p id="title"><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></p><br><p id="description">Posted <?php echo date("F j, Y, g:i A", $row["posted"]); ?> by <i><?php echo $row["author"]; ?></i>.</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I'm really not sure what the issue is here since I usually just do basic queries. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Edit: Forgot to provide the second screenshot:
  [image: [1]:]

Comment: if both tables share the same columns names, you must distinguish them by adding an alias to at least one of them. Also, in the SELECT, you must select the columns and avoid using asterisk, and replaced it with the columns name by the order you want.

Comment: I am not sure about your database schema, but as I see it, for one entry of `cms_discussions`, you can have multiple entries in `cms_discussions_comments`. Thus, if you perform the JOIN operation as you wrote it, you might end up with the same discussion multiple times in your result set if multiple comments of this discussion belong to the last 10 comments.

Comment: @AlanT. How would I be able to forbidden it from doing as you're saying, gathering the last 10 comments from one and same discussion thread? (*cms_discussions*).

Comment: You could use the [DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) keyword and apply it to the `d.id` column. That being said, you might encounter performance issues if you have a lot of entries in your database. Another solution would be to simply have a `last_comment_id` in your `cms_discussions` table so that you can perform your JOIN on this column. It would allow you to access the creation time of the last comment as well which could be a good info to display on your discussions list. Of course, you would have to update a `cms_discussions` entry every time a comment is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your two tables `cms_discussions` and `cms_discussions_comments` both contain an `author` field, one of the twos is not going to be accessible in your result array if you just do `SELECT *`.

What you need to do is to explicitly select fields and assign aliases so that there is no overlaps.

You could do something like:

```
SELECT d.*, c.author AS comment_author FROM cms_discussions d JOIN cms_discussions_comments c ON d.id = c.discussionid ORDER BY c.time DESC LIMIT 10
```

With that query, your `$row['author']` would refer to the field of `cms_discussions` while `$row['comment_author']` would refer to the field of `cms_comments`. That being said, you might want to do the same for other fields like `id`.

---

If you simply do not want to select columns from `cms_discussions_comments` then this will do the trick:

```
SELECT d.* FROM cms_discussions d JOIN cms_discussions_comments c ON d.id = c.discussionid ORDER BY c.time DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I believe you've misunderstod me, I'm not trying to gather any data from cmd_discussions_comments except which has been replied latest to in a order of the *time* row.

Comment: I see, then you have to use `SELECT d.*` instead of `SELECT *` (I updated my answer)

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you.